# Laravel Scout Queue performance

Tags: laravel, amazon-sqs, algolia, laravel-scout

So according to [Laravel Scout Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scout) enabling Queue should improve the performance and should turn data syncing asynchronous. I have setup my queue driver to Amazon SQS and I can confirm my scout syncs are going through it and it's working. However, it seems my performance is worse when the queue is set to True compared to false.

I have made a simple endpoint for the sake of testing and without queue the response time is ~0.1s and with queue it's around ~0.4. This is very strange to me. I have put log's in my code and it doesn't seem to execute things asynchronously. There is seems to be an issue with Scout or Algolia.

I'm wondering if anyone has experienced this before or has any clue what's going on.

PS: My scout is using Algolia

Comment: Long time later, what do you have to say about this? Any interesting information?

Comment: @JeremyBelolo We ended up not using SQS and not async mode